# How to give always 1 file with tornado.web.StaticFileHandler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I need to response with 1 image on any GET requests.

```
def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", ItWorks),
        (r"/logme", MarkerCatchHandler),
        (r"/(robots.\txt)",tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./robots.txt"}),
        (r"/images/(.*)",tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./images/1.png"}),
        (r"/testme/(.*)",tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./images", "default_filename": "1.png"}),
        ],debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888, address = domain_name)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

With http://localhost:8888/testme/3.png i got 404 error

Comment: btw, when i ask http://localhost:8888/robots.txt i got the same error - 404

Comment: overwirte StaticFileHandler's get method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve a single file, you need to pass the folder's name as `path`. Remember not pass the name of the file.

```
# this will serve robots.txt from the current directory
(r"/(robots\.txt)",tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./"}),

# this will only serve 1.png from the images directory
(r"/images/1.png",tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./images"}),

# this will serve all images in the images directory
(r"/testme/(.*)",tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./images"),
```

Comment: I need return the same file for different request. For example, when the user ask for /data/1.png or /data/2.png or data/3.png i must return always the same file even the file does not exists. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you extend the provided `StaticFileHandler` and overwrite `get_absolute_path` (make sure to use the `@classmethod` decorator) to always only use the root and ignore the path.

Something like:

```
import os
import tornado.web

class SingleFileHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
    @classmethod
    def get_absolute_path(cls, root: str, path: str) -> str:
        abspath = os.path.abspath(root)
        return abspath

app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/(.*)", SingleFileHandler, {"path": "./images/always.png"}),
])
app.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Technically you can then also overwrite `validate_absolute_path` to just return the passed `absolute_path` if you need that optimisation.

And if you will have other people use this class, it makes sense to do some config checking - like if the passed `root` is actually a file that you can/are willing to serve to prevent user config errors.